# Esper count with parameters

Tags: esper

I'd like to know if it's possible to use a "count" function or equivalent but with parameters specified, to only count specific results.

So I'd like to do something like:

```
select
    ...
    "nbAccel", count(type='c8y_HarshBehavior' and behaviorType = "ACCELERATION")
    "nbBraking", count(type='c8y_HarshBehavior' and behaviorType = "BRAKING")
    "nbUnknown", count(type='c8y_HarshBehavior' and behaviorType = "UNKNOWN")
from
    ...
```

Let me show you what I want. I'm using the [EPL Online tool](http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html).

Here is my EPL Statements (with the part I pasted above not working, of couse):

```
create schema EventCreated(
  source String,
  type String,
  time Date,
  behaviorType String
);

create schema CreateMeasurement(
  source String,
  type String,
  time Date,
  fragments Object
);



@Name("no_message_20min")
insert into
    EventCreated

select
    e.source as source,
    "c8y_SilentTracker" as type,
    new Date() as time

from pattern [
    every e = EventCreated(
        type != "c8y_HeartbeatReport" and
        type != "c8y_ObdDisconnectionReport" and
        type != "c8y_PowerOffReport" and
        type != "c8y_SilentTracker")

-> (timer:interval(20 minute) and
    not EventCreated(
        source = e.source and
        type != "c8y_HeartbeatReport"))];



@Name("create_context")
create context Trip
    context bySource
        partition by source from EventCreated,

    context byEvents
        start EventCreated(
            type = "c8y_ObdConnectionReport" or
            type = "c8y_PowerOnReport" or
            type = "c8y_FixedReport" or
            type = "c8y_HarshBehaviorReport") as startEvent

        end EventCreated(
            type = "c8y_ObdDisconnectionReport" or
            type = "c8y_PowerOffReport" or
            type = "c8y_SilentTracker") as endEvent;



@Name("context_end")
context Trip
    insert into
        CreateMeasurement

    select
        context.bySource.key1 as source,
        "Trip" as type,
        e.time as time,
        {
            "startedBy", context.byEvents.startEvent.type,
            "startedAt", context.byEvents.startEvent.time,
            "endedBy", e.type,
            "endedAt", e.time,
            "nbAccel", count(type='c8y_HarshBehavior' and behaviorType = "ACCELERATION"),
            "nbBraking", count(type='c8y_HarshBehavior' and behaviorType = "BRAKING"),
            "nbUnknown", count(type='c8y_HarshBehavior' and behaviorType = "UNKNOWN")
        } as fragments

    from
        EventCreated e

    output
        last when terminated;
```

Here is my Time And Event Sequence:

```
EventCreated = {
    source = 'tracker1',
    type = 'c8y_ObdConnectionReport',
    time =  '2016-10-07T10:00:00.000'
}

t = t.plus(5 minutes)

EventCreated = {
    source = 'tracker1',
    type = 'c8y_HarshBehavior',
    time = '2016-10-07 10:05:00.000',
    behaviorType = "UNKNOWN"
}

t = t.plus(5 minutes)

EventCreated = {
    source = 'tracker1',
    type = 'c8y_HarshBehavior',
    time = '2016-10-07 10:10:00.000',
    behaviorType = "ACCELERATION"
}

t = t.plus(5 minutes)

EventCreated = {
    source = 'tracker1',
    type = 'c8y_HarshBehavior',
    time = '2016-10-07 10:15:00.000',
    behaviorType = "BRAKING"
}

t = t.plus(5 minutes)

EventCreated = {
    source = 'tracker1',
    type = 'c8y_Location',
    time='2016-10-07 10:20:00.000'
}

t = t.plus(25 minutes)

EventCreated = {
    source = 'tracker1',
    type = 'c8y_Location',
    time = '2016-10-07 10:45:00.000'
}

t = t.plus(5 minutes)

EventCreated = {
    source = 'tracker1',
    type = 'c8y_ObdDisconnectionReport',
    time = '2016-10-07 10:50:00.000'
}
```

With a Beginning Of Time at 2016-10-07 10:00:00.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found how to do it with the sum function like this:

```
"nbAccel", coalesce(sum(1, type='c8y_HarshBehavior' and behaviorType = "ACCELERATION"), 0),
"nbBraking", coalesce(sum(1, type='c8y_HarshBehavior' and behaviorType = "BRAKING"), 0),
"nbUnknown", coalesce(sum(1, type='c8y_HarshBehavior' and behaviorType = "UNKNOWN"), 0)
```

Comment: Ok but since "count(color='red')" is supported what was the problem in the first place?

Comment: Just copy-paste my example in the EPL Online Tool (link also in the post above) and run it, you'll see the count doesn't work. I get 'nbAccel' = 6, 'nbBraking' = 6, 'nbUnknown' = 6, where I should have 1, 1, 1. Looks like the count somehow doesnt apply the parameters and counts all the events undiscriminately. With the code above using the sums, it works though.

Comment: Too much stuff going on here to see why counts turn out other than expected. I'd recommend removing some indirection to see if the counts get right.

Comment: That "no_message_20min" is triggered by EventCreated and inserts into EventCreated. Perhaps there is something fishy.